# Java regex - multiple substitutions

Tags: java, regex

I need to fetch hostname from a fully qualified domain name String.
All parental domain / subdomain / interface names should be stripped, i.e.

```
abc001 -> abc001     ## stays name ##
efg.fqdn.com -> efg  ## only 1st/short name ##
mnop-int -> mnop     ## only 1st/short name ##
help-adm.fqdn -> help  ## only 1st/short name ##
```

I've tried various combinations similar to this:

```
(.*?)(?:.|-)
```

but it didn't help much.

PS: The regex should be a single-liner, as it is goes as an input in application.

Comment: ... and the Question??

Comment: don't you think **help-adm** and **mnop-int** should be part of answer. i.e. mnop-int.subdomain.domin

Comment: @Manoj, not exactly...if the server is resolvable by a different interface, such as server-int or server-adm we have to  remove the '-int' or '-adm' from it's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement right, you want to get the part of a String before the first dot or hyphen.

In this case, the following regex will work: `"([^.-]*)[.-]?"`. The first match will be the desired String.

Test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] strs = { "abc001", "efg.fqdn.com", "mnop-int", "help-adm.fqdn" };
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^.-]*)[.-]?");
    for (String str : strs) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abc001
efg
mnop
help
```

Comment: yes your understanding is correct, but when I run the regex, it's showing all separated values as output, instead of just the first separated value..

Comment: @Marcos I just re-ran the sample code in my answer and this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Regex flavor other than Java-

`^.*?\\b`

You can `\b` or `word boundary` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tD0dU9/3

word boundary `\b` won't work in this case as Java includes all unicode characters range as a word boundary condition.

Answer (score 0):

As Java's `\b` boundary condition is little bit different than other regular expression engine, We need to take more care when we are using boundary conditions.

```
public class BoundaryCondRegEx {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?<n>\\w+).*$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("mnop-int");
    if(m.matches())
    {
        System.out.print(m.group("n"));
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Nope");

   }

}
```

So As mentioned in pattern `"^(?<n>\\w+).*$"`
`\w` is representing [0-9A-Za-z_]
if your resultant substring is made of these chars, you are fine.